# Check if Expression contains a specific property

Tags: c#

Given a method with a signature like so:

```
MyMethod(params Expression<Func<Subscription, object>>[] fields)
```

That is called like:

```
MyMethod(x=> x.SomeProperty)
```

How can I check which expression was passed to `MyMethod`? Example:

```
MyMethod(Expression<Func<Subscription, object>>[] fields) {
    //using contains like this doesnt seem to work
    if(fields.Contains(x=> x.SomeProperty)) {...}
}
```

Comment: Your question is built on an incorrect assumption. An `Expression` is not necessarily only a property-access operation, it could be a literal-value or another type of expression, e.g. `MyMethod( x => 5 + 2 )`, `MyMethod( x => null )`, or something passed-in by name as part of another expression: `MyMethod( x => this.SomeDelegate( x ).SomeExtensionMethod() ?? 123 )`

Comment: @Dai Thanks. Do you suggest a different parameter signature in order to achieve a similar approach to my example? Note: No need to worry about people doing `x => 5+2` for this use case. The end goal is just to make it easy for a user to specify which properties on an object that they want to specify in a strongly typed way.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and look for property named `SomeProperty` in the expression tree:

```
internal class Finder : ExpressionVisitor {
    private readonly string toFind;
    public Finder(string toFind) {
        this.toFind = toFind;
    }
    public bool IsFound { get; private set; }
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node) {
        IsFound |= node.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property && node.Member.Name == toFind;
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

Use the visitor as follows:

```
static void MyMethod(params Expression<Func<Program,object>>[] fields) {
    foreach (var fieldExpr in fields) {
        var finder = new Finder("Foo");
        finder.Visit(fieldExpr);
        if (finder.IsFound) {
            Console.WriteLine("Expression {0} references 'Foo'", fieldExpr);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Expression {0} does not reference 'Foo'", fieldExpr);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the method like this

```
MyMethod(e => e.Foo, e => e.Bar, e => e.Bar != null ? e.Foo : e.Bar);
```

produces this output:

```
Expression e => e.Foo references 'Foo'
Expression e => e.Bar does not reference 'Foo'
Expression e => IIF((e.Bar != null), e.Foo, e.Bar) references 'Foo'
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/wpiQDr)

Answer (score 0):

An Expression is very generic. You might first need to filter the fields that are `MemberExpression`:

```
public static void MyMethod(params Expression<Func<Subscription, object>>[] fields)
{
    var memberExpressions = fields
        .Where(f => typeof(MemberExpression).IsAssignableFrom(f.Body.GetType()))
        .Select(f => (MemberExpression)f.Body)
        .ToList();
    if (memberExpressions.Any(ex => 
        ex.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property &&
        ex.Member.Name == "SomeProperty"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("At least one of the fields expressions passed to this function were x => x.SomeProperty");
    }
}
```